# A probability exercise

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a problem understanding the first part of this question :

> In a certain town, at time $t = 0$ there are no bears. Brown bears and grizzly bears arrive as
>   independent Poisson processes with respective rates $\beta$ and γ.
>
> (a) What is the probability that a brown bear is the first to arrive?

I know that I have to calculate $P( T < U)$ where $T$ and $U$ are respectively random variables describing the time arrival of brown and grizzly bears, but this seems weird for me.

Comment: Why does it seem weird to you?

Comment: it seems weird since we usually work out the probability that a random variable (upper case) is smaller than a realization (lower case) such as P( T< t), Then can apply the formula. But in this case, I don't understand how to calculate this probability.

Comment: Grizzly bears are brown bears.  Just saying.  Black bears are different.

Comment: @lulu : 
What's the Difference Between Grizzly Bears. ... The difference is regional: bears found inland are referred to as grizzlies, while those on the coasts are known as brown bears. Grizzlies are actually a subspecies of brown bear, Ursus arctos horribilis, found in dense forests, alpine meadows and mountain valleys.

Comment: @yassinemab  Exactly.  All grizzly bears are brown bears.  Not all brown bears are grizzly bears.  Probably not the point of the exercise, but still.

Comment: @lulu : yes you'r  right.

Answer (score 1):

$T$ and $U$ are independent exponential random variables with parameters $\beta$ and $\gamma$ so $P(T<U)=\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{u}\beta e^{-\beta t} dt \gamma e^{-\gamma u} du$.  I will let you evaluate this integral.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know this formula, can you please tell me how to find it?

Comment: @yassinemab ,they are independent;  so, imagine the 2D plane of the variable T and U. Over which region does it seem reasonable to integrate and find the probability? Given that T<U?